# How to redefine the theorem environment like beamer?

Tags: theorems, tcolorbox, etoolbox

I am trying to prepare a slides from the lecture notes which is already prepared in latex. If the notes is not prepared already, `tcbtheorem` is a wellknown way to showcase the theorem environment. But somehow I cant use it because 
`tcbtheorem` uses two arguments for title and reference like

```
\begin{definition}{Elementary Set}{label here}

defintion goes here

\end{definition}
```

whereas, we have already typed as

```
\begin{definition}[Elementary Set]\label{def:elementaryset}
            If $A$ is union of a finite number of intervals, $A$ is said to be an elementary set. Set of all elementary sets in ${\mathbb{R}}^p$ is denoted by $\mathcal{E}$.
        \end{definition}
```

in all the  50page notes  in `amsthm` style. So, the way to acheive what we want is to  redefine the theorem environment so that it look like beamer theorem environment. For that purpose, I have taken `etoolbox` and `tcolorbox` as a tool. Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[serif,fontsize=11pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox,amssymb}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\AtBeginEnvironment{definition}{\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Definition]}
    \AtEndEnvironment{definition}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{definition}[Elementary Set]\label{def:elementaryset}
        If $A$ is union of a finite number of intervals, $A$ is said to be an elementary set. Set of all elementary sets in ${\mathbb{R}}^p$ is denoted by $\mathcal{E}$.
    \end{definition}


\end{document}
```

The out shows something like,

[image]

### My requirement:

`Definition 0.1(Elementary set)`
should come in the title of the tcolorbox.

### How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!! TeX masters...

Comment: Why don't you use the `\newtcbtheorem` macro instead?

Comment: I already have hand ready document with me as lecture notes..@ChristianHupfer

Comment: And `tcbtheorem` uses two arguments for title and reference like `\begin{definition}{Elementary Set}{label here}` which I may not be able to change in my lecture notes..right??

Comment: You should add this information to your post.

Comment: Thanks for the notices. I have edited my question @ChristianHupfer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `\newtcbtheorem` has a different setup, especially with the label argument, I suggest to use a `\renewtcolorbox{definition}` and faking the title line.

Using `beamer` option even provides the `beamer` look.

The label mechanism is done either with `label=` or `\label` if the `\@currentlabel` macro is defined manually in `before upper={\protected@edef\@currentlabel{...}}` -- but using `label=` is the better way to go here.

```
\documentclass[serif,fontsize=11pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox,amssymb}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]



\makeatletter
\renewtcolorbox[use counter=definition,number within=section]{definition}[1][]{
  enhanced,beamer,
  title={Definition \thedefinition\ (#1)},
  before upper={\protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@definition\endcsname\csname thedefinition\endcsname}}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[Elementary Set] \label{Foo}
  If $A$ is union of a finite number of intervals, $A$ is said to be an elementary set. Set of all elementary sets in ${\mathbb{R}}^p$ is denoted by $\mathcal{E}$.
\end{definition}

See \ref{Foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Its perfectly what I want..but the reference is not working..

Comment: @David. Your example does not have a reference

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have edited my post just when you were answering my question. And this does not break through pages as it does in tcbtheorem. Any help regarding that?

Comment: @David: Oh my, just use `breakable` as option ...

Comment: @Christian..Yeah..thank you so much..It works like a charm..Kindly help me in reference please.

Comment: @David: I did the reference already

Comment: OMG....You are really genius..Thank you so much for the help..All works very fine..@ChristianHupfer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I vote always Christian and you?:-)